# Answering someone's questions

Tags: torah-study

It says in Kedushin Daf 30:

> תנו רבנן ושננתם שיהו דברי תורה מחודדים בפיך שאם ישאל לך אדם דבר אל
>   תגמגם ותאמר לו אלא אמור לו מיד שנאמר אמור אמור לחכמה אחותי את וגו

Chazal are telling us that one should know the Torah in such a way that if someone will ask you a question you should be able to answer them immediately without "stuttering" and trying to figure out or remember the answer (or having to look it up.) This is of course a high level that everyone should strive to reach. My question is, if (for example) Reuvan comes along and asks Shimon a question in Torah and Shimon simply doesn't know the answer. Does Shimon now have a "responsibility" (for a lack of a better word at the moment) to go out and find the answer or to go learn whatever it is in order that next time he should answer immediately.

Many times (in personal experience) you will speak to someone in learning that may or may not have an interest in what you are asking. But it turns out the person doesn't know the answer. They think "that's it" and will move on with their lives after speaking to you. Is Chazal perhaps telling us that "no! One must know/learn everything and if the answer is not known they must go out and learn it in order to answer the second time around. While it would obviously be a good idea to learn what you don't know, perhaps one wouldn't be responsible again in answering right away if in fact they wouldn't learn it.

Again the question boils down to the following. From this Gemorah could one say that if a person is unable to respond accordingly to a question being asked in Torah they then *must* go out and learn it in order to properly respond the second time around.

(As always provide all sources.)

Comment: In the Chassideshe way of thinking: if it came your way it means it has a Shaychus to you, so even if no one will ask you that question ever again you and your Neshama need to know the answer.

Comment: @MeirZirkind Although looking for something in nigleh, a source for this would also be good!

Comment: See this general idea brought in the name of the Baal Shem Tov in Likkutey Sichos vol. 10 pg.  24 (that since every minute occurrence is by hashgocha protis, there is a reason he saw such a thing).

Comment: Though it says in the beginning of Shabbos that one shouldn't ask a question on another if the other isn't involved in that sugya, since he may make a mistake.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin +1 on the comment. Source for that: כי קאי רבי בהא מסכתא לא תשייליה במסכתא אחריתי דילמא לאו אדעתיה דאי לאו דרבי גברא רבה הוא כספתיה (top of Shabbos 3b). Someone so proficient in all topics would be considered a *gavra rabba*, exceptional among scholars.