# Does a Rov have to answer a question?

Tags: torah-study, rabbis

In the past [I asked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/answering-someones-questions) what responsibility does a person have to look up and investigate an answer to a question that he wasn't able to answer.

I'd now like to ask a similar question with a few points.

If a Rov is asked a practical question, are they required to respond (if they know the answer) or can they say "go ask another Rov" if they don't wish to be bothered (or feel it will take away from their learning.) If they don't know the answer at all, are they required now to look it up? Being that they are a Rov and have a certain responsibility to those asking questions.

Comment: I had a similar story I saw myself with one of the rabbeim and heard a similar one about one of the gedolim, who refused to paskin for a different reason - if they would paskin, the decision would not be the one they felt was appropriate for the person under the circumstances.

Comment: Rav Moshe Feinstein indirectly comments on this in his hakdama to igros moshe: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14673&st=&pgnum=3

Comment: @Yehoshua: What do you mean by "Rov?"  A shul rabbi \ community leader?  Or just someone with semicha?

Comment: @gt6989b - Why didn't they feel they could give a pesak that would have been appropriate?

Comment: @ShmuelL Because they did not hold of that shittah. This one had to do with abortion with TESACS I think, and he saw the parents would not be able to handle his *psak* so he sent them to a different *rav* who was known to rule differently.